# adobe flash cs4 as3: get current directory of a running project?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, working-directory

is there a way to get the current directory of the project?  i'm trying to load images using dynamic paths and it seems that the link is broken. but seeing the current directory of the running project i'll be able to make sure that my picture links are valid.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either using AIR on your end, or a server-side script on the internets.
There are security measures put in flash to prevent anyone from doing damage to your computer from flash, so you may not be able to do that. But if you're having issues accessing stuff it may also be due to access permissions, you can access either local or network resources and I think it defaults to network.